# mysql left join order by null values to the end

Tags: mysql

mysql

```
SELECT * FROM media
LEFT JOIN media_priority
ON (media_priority.media_id = media.id AND media_priority.media_tag = '".$tag."')
WHERE something = 'something'
ORDER BY media_priority.media_order;
```

This works fine except that media_priority.media_order sometimes comes back as null and mysql puts the null values at the top.

So I was trying to figure out how to do an IS NULL AS tempcol statement with my left join so I can order by that first.....I just can't seem to get the syntax right.

Where would I put the IS NULL statement in my query above?

I was thinking something like:

```
LEFT JOIN media_priority
ON (media_priority.media_id = media.id AND media_priority.media_tag = '".$tag."')
media_priority.media_order IS NULL AS isnull
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN media_priority.media_order IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
    media_priority.media_order;
```

Or use a magic number if you have some upper limit which `media_order` will never feasibly reach.

```
ORDER BY 
    COALESCE( media_priority.media_order,99999999);
```

The first approach is obviously somewhat safer!

Comment: Your answer is better than mine. I've done this in the past too, don't know why it didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 13):

I recommend ordering by the boolean value of `media_priority.media_order IS NULL` first, then the column value, in order to force the NULLs to the end.

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM media
LEFT JOIN media_priority
ON (media_priority.media_id = media.id AND media_priority.media_tag = '".$tag."')
WHERE something = 'something'
ORDER BY (media_priority.media_order IS NULL) ASC, media_priority.media_order ASC;
```